# jQuery keyup event not working properly

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){

  $("input.custom").hide();
  $("input.custom").wrap("<div class='customInput'></div>");
  $(".customInput").html("Type");

  $(document).on("keyup", ".customInput", function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
  });

});
```

html

```
...
<body>
  <input type="text" class="custom" />
</body>
...
```

i've a code like this and it should give an alert of the keycode if a keyboard button is pressed while .customInput is focused.. but it's not working

Little like [THIS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_keycode)
Jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/uy8mX/)

Comment: it works but with all elements in body... i just want to call alert only when .customInput is focused @ElmoVanKielmo

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer and the fiddle - one trick is required for div to capture keystrokes

Comment: not working pal... its still alerting even it's focused outside the .customInput

Comment: Ah, of course - now the link to the fiddle is updated

Comment: awesome :D please explain how this works

Comment: Some explanation added in the footer of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't have an input with class `customInput`.
Do it like this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".custom", function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

Or if you want to do bind the event do the `div.customInput` element:

```
// Add tabIndex to div - this makes the div selectable and enables keyboard events on it
$("input.custom").wrap("<div class='customInput' tabIndex='1'></div>");

$('.customInput').keyup(function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

Here is the fiddle for the second option - http://jsfiddle.net/WQL4X/4/
Normally `div` won't capture key events but if it's selectable it does. To make it selectable you have to provide `tabIndex` attribute. That's it.

Comment: no i'm trying to do something like this (without input) http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_keycode

Comment: i want to bind it with .customInput element only

Comment: Then you've confused us because in the example you've linked the handler is bound to body.

Comment: even if its binded to the body it doesnt work... i tried